# Added space when reading from file in C++

Tags: c++

When I read a string with `getline` method in C++ it's adding a space in front of my string.

What should I do to eliminate that?

This is my code:

```
void read_from_file(_Longlong mobile_number) {
  string number = to_string(mobile_number);
  fstream read(number + "messages_not_seen.txt", ios::in);
  _Longlong mobile_numer;
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  char txt[500];
  int Priority;
  while (read) {
    read >> first_name >> last_name >> mobile_numer;
    read.getline(txt, 500);
    if (read.eof()) {
      break;
    }
    push(mobile_numer, first_name, last_name, txt);
  }
}
```

Comment: This question may be liable to **downvoting** due to grammatical errors. Also, it is recommended to improve your code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using modern C++ (C++-11 and up), you can use lambdas in order to do so.

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // not recommended, but I assume you're a beginner.

// trim from start (in place)
static inline void ltrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int ch) {
        return !std::isspace(ch);
    }));
}
void read_from_file(_Longlong mobile_number)
{
    string number = to_string(mobile_number);
    fstream read(number + "messages_not_seen.txt", ios::in);
    _Longlong mobile_numer;
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    // char txt[500]; // why are you using C-style char here?
    string txt; // use string instead

    int Priority;
    while (read)
    {
        read >> first_name >> last_name >> mobile_number;
        ltrim(read.get(cin, txt));
        if (read.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
        push(mobile_numer, first_name, last_name, txt);
    }
}
```

And don't forget the `main` function where you invoke all of these.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator leaves delimiting whitespace in the stream. Usually, it's not a problem because the `>>` operator will also ignore leading whitespace, but if you use `getline()` after the extraction, the space will get included into the string.

You can ignore leading spaces with something like

```
while (std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(std::cin.peek()))) std::cin.ignore();
```

Or just call `cin.ignore()` once if you're sure there is exactly one leading space.

Something you might find helpful is the non-member [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function, which works with `std::string` instead of character arrays.